# Find out MongoDB MapReduce opid

Tags: c#, mongodb, mapreduce

I am running multiple long running mapreduce operations on MongoDB and I would like to get the opid for that operation as it runs. Using C# driver, `MapReduce` call is blocking, so it comes back after the operation is complete.

I would like to be able to tag mapreduce operations so that I can check their progress and the only way I could think of at the moment is to create a javascript variable with a unique identifier and iterate over the output of `db.currentOp` looking for that variable. Is there a better way to do that?

Code in question:

```
MongoCollection<BsonDocument> logCollection = database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("source_collection");

BsonJavaScript map = new BsonJavaScript(@"function() {    //map     }");
BsonJavaScript reduce = new BsonJavaScript(@"function(key,values){    //reduce    }");

var builder = new MapReduceOptionsBuilder();
builder.SetOutput("output_collection");

MapReduceResult mapReduceResult = logCollection.MapReduce(map, reduce, builder); //<--- Blocks until the mapreduce job completes
```

What I would **like** to do is submit mapreduce as a job asynchronously and check its progress as it runs like so (note the made up `MapReduceJob` class):

```
MongoCollection<BsonDocument> logCollection = database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("source_collection");

BsonJavaScript map = new BsonJavaScript(@"function() {    //map     }");
BsonJavaScript reduce = new BsonJavaScript(@"function(key,values){    //reduce    }");

var builder = new MapReduceOptionsBuilder();
builder.SetOutput("output_collection");

MapReduceJob job = logCollection.StartMapReduce(map, reduce, builder); //<--- Returns straight away

while (true)
{
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    var operationDoc = database.GetCurrentOp();
    var operations = operationDoc["inprog"].AsBsonArray;
    var thisOperation = operations.FirstOrDefault(op => op["opid"] == job.OpId);
    if (thisOperation == null)
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about making the MapReduceJob create a new thread to execute the blocking map reduce call? You should be able to easily tell if the map reduce job finishes by maintaining a properly synchronized flag that tells you if it is done or not.

Comment: Not quite. If the job runs past the timeout the MapReduce call will throw a timeout exception but the job will continue to run. It also doesn't let me track the progress, which is possible using `currentOp` output.

Comment: In that case, you really have to poll the $cmd.sys.inprog collection for the map reduce job. I am not really familiar with the API for the C# driver, but you can actually attach arbitrary tags on the mr query like this in js: db.mr.mapReduce(m, r, {out: inline, myTag: 'jobID12'}). However, this only works if your m and r functions are small, otherwise it will display "query not recording (too large)".